# Trying to follow an answer on here to show git branches in my terminal, but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, git, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 18, and I've added the following to my `.bashrc`:

```
# GIT
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$(parse_git_branch) $ "
```

I reload the `.bashrc` but after I restart my terminal and go to my folder which contains a git repo, the branch still does not show up.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, this worked fine for me in my macbook.

Can someone help me? Thanks

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# GIT
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$(parse_git_branch) $ '

# INFINALITY FONT RENDERING CONFIG
. /etc/infinality-settings.sh

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm|xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w \$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/mint-fortune ]; then
     /usr/bin/mint-fortune
fi
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [official git prompt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes.  Written as you have it, the `parse_git_branch` is being run only once: when PS1 is intially assigned.  By using single quotes, it will be run every time PS1 is evaluated.

```
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch) $ '
```

Comment: hi.  i tried that but it still doesn't work.  may i post my full bashrc?

Comment: Your bashrc is not necessary.  Just do `echo $PS1`

Comment: You should drop the backslash before the `$`.  Editing answer.

Comment: :(  i did that and still doesn't work.  not sure what's wrong

Comment: What is the text you are actually seeing in your prompt?

Comment: You are assigning `PS1` more than once in your .bashrc.  Later assignments are still using double quotes.

Comment: `me@mint ~/Development/react/media $ git status
On branch dev-2
nothing to commit, working directory clean
`

Comment: I know I don't really know why those other ones are there.  Should I delete those?

Comment: Yes.  Or delete your new assignments, and edit those as needed.

Comment: for now im just gonna get rid of the colors lol i will figure that out later.  i just need the branch.  i removed the other stuff that was there.